# How to check iOS camera, 3D Touch and other hardware's works or not - programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-camera

Do you know iOS device-level API available to do on-device checks on - whether device 3D Touch working or not Camera works or not and to check all the required hardwares current status and then share it with device replacement team to replace the device if it’s under warranty.

Use case:
Lets think about the use case like. Telecommunication companies who give iPhone at the plan - They have sales data in their database, would like to offer this as additional feature like "Self diagnostic" that will check what all possible hardware status like camera, Touch ID etc and also check if device is under warranty and will trigger request for fix/repair/replacement automatically or with user consent

Something similar to Device Check API's
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck

Comment: You think, sale's records for those devices that you are talking about are somehow stored somewhere?  How does that work?

Comment: Yes lets think about the use case like. 
Telecommunication companies who give iPhone at the plan - They have sales data in their database, would like to offer this as additional feature like "Self diagnostic" that will check what all possible hardware status like camera, Touch ID etc and also check if device is under warranty and will trigger request for fix/repair/replacement automatically or with user consent.